# Preventing rounding of Mathematica expressions

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

When using Mathematica, the following expression is given:

```
In[429]:= 100*(1 - 0.002)^5*(1 - 0.005)*(1 - 0.006)*3.5
Out[430]= 342.7127137548418
```

I tried using N[], SetPrecision[] etc.. and couldn't get the real value which is `342.712713754841762864` according to the [website](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%2a%281%20-%200.002%29%5E5%2a%281%20-%200.005%29%2a%281%20-%200.006%29%2a3.5&dataset=).

How do I prevent Mathematica from rounding the result?

Comment: You could use `N[100*(1 - 2/1000)^5*(1 - 5/1000)*(1 - 6/1000)*35/10, 30]`, or provide the input with greater precision.

Comment: But why does Mathematica round my result as soon as I'm using float values? I still want to be able to use decimal values AND get a precise result. How do I provide input with a greater precision? Because SetPrecision doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I mean, the website seems to handle my expression very well. Why won't Mathematica do the same?

Comment: this is well addressed in the last question  you asked..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864033/python-decimal-decimal-precision-doesnt-match-wolfram-alphas/19876715#19876715

Answer (score 1):

Idk, whether you have already found the answer but you can just `FullForm` of your expression. I am really in shock that it is so difficult in my case compute accurately `4852.95 + 14000`.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can, but shouldn't.

If you want extra precision on your results, you can enter `` 123.456`digits of precision `` on all of your decimal numbers to set the precision of them and their results. This would turn your original expression into something such as `` 100*(1 - 0.002`25)^5*(1 - 0.005`25)*(1 - 0.006`25)*3.5`25 ``, which gives the expected result of `342.7127137548417628640000`. Note however, that Mathematica mainly works well with explicit rational numbers, such as `1/200`, for getting exact results. However, beyond the precision, I have seen no other problems inherent in floating-point values.